# Bootstrapping using @distributed in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, statistics-bootstrap

I want to do a simple Monte Carlo bootstrap type simulation in Julia. Just started learning Julia and found out there is a way to do things parallel using @distributed. So I wrote this simple code, but after spending I really couldn't understand why it is failing. Some help would really help me to learn

```
using Random, RCall, StatsBase, HypothesisTests, Suppressor, Distributed, BenchmarkTools, Statistics
@everywhere using Random, RCall, StatsBase, HypothesisTests, Suppressor, Distributed, BenchmarkTools, Statistics; rmprocs(workers()); addprocs(4); nworkers()

function setup(n, B, nl, sl)

    take_counter = @distributed (+) for m in 1:nl
        Y = randn(n)
        mean_Y = mean(Y)

        counter = 0
        for i = 1:B
                Y_st = sample(Y, n, replace = true)
                mean_Y_st = mean(Y_st)  


                if mean_Y_st > mean_Y
                    counter += 1
                end
        end
        p_value = counter/B


        if p_value < sl  
            1
        else 
            0
        end
    end
    take_counter  

 end    

take_counter = setup(25, 200, 40, 0.05)
```

If I run I get a huge error, some help could be really useful. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: "If I run I get a huge error": Please share this error :). It makes it easier to help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not checked your code in detail (in particular - I did not check if it calculates what you want), but simply rewritten it to retain what was needed for it to run.

This code works for me:

```
using Distributed

rmprocs(workers()); addprocs(4); nworkers()

@everywhere using Statistics

function setup(n, B, nl, sl)
    @distributed (+) for m in 1:nl
        Y = randn(n)
        mean_Y = mean(Y)
        counter = 0
        for i = 1:B
                Y_st = rand(Y, n)
                mean_Y_st = mean(Y_st)  
                if mean_Y_st > mean_Y
                    counter += 1
                end
        end
        p_value = counter / B
        Int(p_value < sl)
    end
end

take_counter = setup(25, 200, 40, 0.05)
```

(it is essentially identical with few minor twists). Please let me know if it works or fails for you so we can diagnose your problem further.

EDIT: Now I have looked through your code and I can see where is the problem. You first run `@everywhere` and then remove and add workers. This means that fresh workers do not have `@everywhere` run on them. You have to run `@everywhere` after adding the workers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestions helped to fix the code, thank you so much. Just started using Julia (Thanks to my friend Tileaman Conring also), I was thinking whether I would get an answer here but really thankful to you and the StackOverflow community who are using Julia. It made me more inspired to use Julia.

Comment: @Shaikh - I have fixed one line in my code. It should be `Y_st = rand(Y, n)` which takes `n` samples from `Y` with replacement. Earlier I have written `rand(Y)` which smpled only one element from `Y`. Sorry for a bug.

Comment: No problem, thanks for fixing, I just changed the first portion and it worked nicely!